# How to connect an Android device on Windows

Tags: android, usb

Hello I can't see my Android device on Windows when I connect it via USB. I can't see any device debug logging in Eclipse when I plug in the device via USB.

Is there any Android driver for USB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install [these](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) drivers, or you download them from your manufacturer's website.